# Layering a table view and a google map view iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to set up a map search using the google maps sdk in ios. So far, I have the autocompleted search working correctly and when I search, the results show up in a tableview. I want to be able to click on a cell in the table view and reveal the map, then show the table again when the user touches back into the search box. My strategy to do this is to layer the mapview and the table view in the same view Controller, and show/hide or push whichever view to the top. However, because the google map is not part of mapkit, I'm not sure that I can manipulate it like this. Please let me know if you know an easy way to do this. Setting the view to tableview also results in a black screen

mapView.hidden just reveals a black screen

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()
    view.bringSubviewToFront(self.tableView)
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
        longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    //mapView.hidden = true

    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView
    self.view = self.tableView
    var marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView

}
```

I am using the google maps cocoapod

Comment: Can you provide any of your code for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I had to add my own subview, change the class of that subview to GMSMapview and assign the map to that subview.

```
var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
        longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)

    var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true

    self.mapSubView.camera = camera
    self.mapSubView = mapView
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the order which they have in the view controller's list of subviews. If `mapView` and `tableView` are both direct subviews of the root `view`, you can just call [insertSubview:belowSubview:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview:belowSubview:)

```
[self.view insertSubview:mapView belowSubview:tableView];
```

and vice versa.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the google maps view isn't in the subviews array. I could be wrong but I think the sdk just throws it on top.

Comment: It's nice answer for who use tableview for google places autocomplete along with google maps.